# SQL query to get record from tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I have a small query to be answered.
There are 4 tables call it as

```
user : uid, uname
category: cid,canme
product : pid, pname
assemble : aid, uid,pid,cid;
```

I want to display a record from product table but the requirement is pid(from product) and uid (from user) should not be present in assemble table in the same row at a time.

Comment: Please show some sample data _and_ the query you have already tried.

Comment: how to get relation between `user` and `product` table to get pid(from product) and uid (from user) should not be present in assemble table in the same row at a time

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
select * from user u, product p, assemble a where p.pid not in 
(Select pid from assemble) and u.uid not in (select uid from assemble)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/558f4/4) and the comments within. You're covering a lot of concepts here, and you'll want to think about your design and what you're trying to accomplish, but to address the goals you've set forth in your question:

1. You can use [PRIMARY KEYS](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-primary-key/) or [UNIQUE CONSTRAINTS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-constraints.html) to ensure that duplicate values don't get inserted into your tables (e.g., you don't want `pid` and `cid` to be duplicated in the assemble table, so I made that the primary key). I'm being very literal with your statement:

> the requirement is pid(from product) and uid (from user) ***should not be present*** in assemble table in the same row at a time. <sub><sup>*(emphasis mine)*</sup></sub>

2. You can use [JOINS](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/joins.php) to relate items from different tables to one another. In fact, your assemble table is often referred to as a "join table". My example is using inner joins (meaning, values must exist in both tables).
3. You can use [FOREIGN KEYS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-fk.html) to ensure that columns you want to reference in another table exist there.

Below is the code in case SQL Fiddle misbehaves.

Create and populate the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  uid serial,
  uname text,
  CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uid)
  );

CREATE TABLE categories (
  cid serial,
  cname text,
  CONSTRAINT cat_pkey PRIMARY KEY (cid)
  );

 CREATE TABLE products (
   pid serial,
   pname text,
  CONSTRAINT prod_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pid)
   );

 CREATE TABLE assemble (
   join_id serial,
   uid bigint,
   pid bigint,
   cid bigint,
   CONSTRAINT assemble_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uid, pid),
   CONSTRAINT assemble_user_fkey FOREIGN KEY (uid)
      REFERENCES users (uid),
   CONSTRAINT assemble_prod_fkey FOREIGN KEY (pid)
      REFERENCES products (pid),
   CONSTRAINT assemble_cat_fkey FOREIGN KEY (cid)
      REFERENCES categories (cid)
   );

INSERT INTO users (uname) VALUES ('Akshay');
INSERT INTO users (uname) VALUES ('Mom');
INSERT INTO users (uname) VALUES ('Dad');

INSERT INTO categories (cname) VALUES ('Shoes');
INSERT INTO categories (cname) VALUES ('Hats');
INSERT INTO categories (cname) VALUES ('Coats');

INSERT INTO products (pname) VALUES ('Blue Suede Nikes');
INSERT INTO products (pname) VALUES ('Fedora');
INSERT INTO products (pname) VALUES ('Flying Jacket');

-- Give Akshay a hat
INSERT INTO assemble (uid, cid, pid)
   VALUES (
     (SELECT uid FROM users WHERE uname='Akshay'),
     (SELECT cid FROM categories WHERE cname='Hats'),
     (SELECT pid FROM products WHERE pname='Fedora')
   );

-- Give Mom a coat
INSERT INTO assemble (uid, cid, pid)
   VALUES (
     (SELECT uid FROM users WHERE uname='Mom'),
     (SELECT cid FROM categories WHERE cname='Coats'),
     (SELECT pid FROM products WHERE pname='Flying Jacket')
   );

-- Give Dad some shoes
INSERT INTO assemble (uid, cid, pid)
   VALUES (
     (SELECT uid FROM users WHERE uname='Dad'),
     (SELECT cid FROM categories WHERE cname='Shoes'),
     (SELECT pid FROM products WHERE pname='Blue Suede Nikes')
   );
```

Queries:

```
-- get the data out of your assemble table, with names from related tables
SELECT u.uname, c.cname, p.pname
FROM users u
INNER JOIN assemble j
   ON u.uid = j.uid
INNER JOIN categories c
   ON j.cid = c.cid
INNER JOIN products p
   ON p.pid = j.pid;

-- Give Mom the same coat... this will fail due to the PRIMARY KEY, even with a different category
INSERT INTO assemble (uid, cid, pid)
   VALUES (
     (SELECT uid FROM users WHERE uname='Mom'),
     (SELECT cid FROM categories WHERE cname='Hats'),
     (SELECT pid FROM products WHERE pname='Flying Jacket')
   );
```

Comment: I believe that this won't work from how I read/interpret ***pid(from product) and uid (from user) should not be present in assemble table in the same row at a time***. This would require both to be present. Rather I believe that CHECK constraints would be suitable to enforce only one or the other.

Comment: Hmm, your interpretation might be right. I'm reading it as the _combination_ of (pid, uid) can't be duplicated, but strictly, your interpretation could be correct.